# Display Data's metabox in page

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, metabox

I created a metabox has a textarea in page admin,
So after validating the data is saved, but it's not displayed in the page (theme) I hope I explain well my problem.

here is my code :

```
<?php



add_action('add_meta_boxes','dar_meta_create');

function dar_meta_create()
{
    add_meta_box(  
        'dar_meta', // $id  
        'metabox dardar', // $title   
        'dar_meta_function', // $callback  
        'page', // $page  
        'normal', // $context  
        'high');
}

// callback

function dar_meta_function($post)
{
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'dar_nonce');


    // get value of text area
    $shortcode = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_shortcode',true);
    echo 
    '<textarea name="_shortcode" id="_shortcode">'.wp_kses_post($shortcode).'</textarea>';
}

// save meta box



function dar_meta_save($id,$post)
{

// check the autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
        return $id; 

    if (
        'page' == $post->post_type
        && current_user_can('edit_page', $id)
        && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['dar_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))
        && isset($_POST['_shortcode'])
    ) update_post_meta($id, '_shortcode', strip_tags($_POST['_shortcode']));


}
add_action('save_post','dar_meta_save');
```

And Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, all you posted is backend functionality.

Ob the frontend you have to actively display the data, as you already did in the backend.

Like so:

```
// assuming you're in the Loop on your INDIVIDUAL page template
echo wp_kses_post(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_shortcode', true));
```

If you don't have an individual template file, you have to check for the page ID, for instance like so.

```
// assuming you're in the Loop on your GENERAL page template
if (is_page(YOUR-PAGE-ID))
    echo wp_kses_post(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_shortcode', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the metabox on the back end and saved the metadata into the Database, which is actually the hard part for most people. With that said, you haven't written any display code. You should probably review get_post_custom() and its related methods in the Codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

The data is there, you just have to output it to the template.

Comment: No problem man. I mean, like I said, you did the hard part. I normally just point people at ACF unless they're really dead set on writing from the codex.